# Is the structure of "a/an X kind of Y" correct?

Tags: grammaticality, nouns, adjectives

Is this structure correct or not?

> An orange kind of morning is desired.

Can I replace X with a noun like *Europe,Japan,India* etc. or not? For example:

> An India kind of morning is desired after experiencing a black winter for 6 months.

Comment: No. None of it makes sense.

Comment: Why are they incorrect?

Comment: As you said in your question you are looking for adjectives for the morning.  Are "Japan", "India", "Europe" adjectives? No.

Comment: I am not looking for anything unless to know 1. Is this structure correct or not. 2. Can I replace X with a noun or not.

Comment: The structure of 1. is correct.  Your choice of adjective in 1 is dubious semantically.  You may not replace X with a noun; it requires an adjective.

Comment: So why are you sending your answer in comments? I think comment were for improving questions as far as I remember specially when there is another one who disagrees with you in first comment.

Comment: Because I try not to provide real answers to questions that I feel are likely to get closed. But I don't like leaving the OP completely in the lurch either.

Comment: Post Chomsky (1957), it's utterly pointless to speculate on whether [Colorless green ideas sleep furiously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colorless_green_ideas_sleep_furiously), or OP's constructions here, are "correct". This Q is Not Constructive.

Comment: Why do you think this question is likely to be closed when there are two different users who are providing different answers?

Comment: @ Persian Cat. Because it's a pointless question!

Comment: @FumbleFingers Sorry but I disagree with you. It is a question about grammar which is on-topic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Guess you gotta be in a Persia state of mind.

Comment: @StoneyB Never! He is always in a British state of mind. If you were right he was nicer than it! :))

Comment: @FumbleFingers I read the trick of Chomsky. These are really different examples with mostly a similar appearance.

Comment: @ Persian Cat: Your examples are no different to Chomsky's. Sure, it's *grammatically* possible to use a word that's normally a noun as an adjective, but *"a Europe morning"*, for example, is effectively gibberish. ELL is hardly the right place to discuss exotic/poetic constructions that wouldn't normally mean anything even to native speakers, let alone *learners*. Take it to [writers.se](http://writers.stackexchange.com/) if you really want to discuss such non-standard usage.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Yes Sir! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*A [PLACENAME] kind of* is not a frequent construction, but it is hardly rare; you may encounter it in phrases like these, plucked from Google hits:

- He is a New York kind of guy — smart, fast, sophisticated.
- It's a Paris kind of a month: seems like I have a lot of projects this month that have a Parisian theme.
- I have never particularly wanted to visit India (I am more a Europe kind of gal) but you make it sound great.
- Cool tatami rooms really gives you a Japan kind of vibe. Waitresses are dressed in kimonos.

But you have to be careful in using it. In the first place, it is very colloquial: you will not encounter it in academic expository prose. In the second place, it is a calculated and knowing sort of expression: people who employ it usually do so somewhat self-consciously, fully aware that they are deliberately flouting the conventional use with an adjective rather than a noun. And in the third place, you usually need to explain just what you mean: you see that explicitly in three of these examples and implicitly in the "Europe" one (a "Europe kind of gal" clearly means the writer prefers to visit Europe).

However, your starting with *an orange kind of morning* (which is not transparently meaningful) suggests a use outside these restraints: odd phrases of this sort are very common in poetry, particularly in poetry of the second quarter of the last century. There of course the restraints of formal discourse do not apply; **everything** is self-conscious; and explanations are not called for, because shocking the reader out of semantic complacency is often a primary objective.

Comment: Thanks! Nice and useful! Surely I am aware that it sounds poetic not academic but I was not sure about correctness,etc. About my example... I didn't think about it a lot but it means an orange morning not for example a grey one! :)

Comment: @PersianCat Ah! We say *red sky*: "Red sky at night, sailor's delight; Red sky in the morning, sailors take warning."

Comment: And... What about Arthur C Clarke kind of Optimism? I made this in comments of EL&U site at the second and really do not know how this kind of structure and wording I used! But I meant a kind of famous optimism about the progress of science and technology in the near future and as all of us know none of Arthur C Clarke's predictions happened! I really do not remember any kind of scientific prediction with this amount of deviation from the reality of future!

Comment: @PersianCat That's an acceptable locution (but you don't capitalise Optimism unless it's a formal theory with that name).