# How to parse 'told Ron so'?

Tags: sentence-construction

> Harry didn't think there was anything wrong with not being able to
>   afford an owl. After all, he'd never had any money in his life until a
>   month ago, and he **told Ron so**, all about having to wear Dudley's
>   old clothes and never getting proper birthday presents. This seemed to
>   cheer Ron.
>
> (Harry Potter and the Sorcerer's Stone)

Is the construction of ‘told Ron so’ ‘verb + indirect object + direct object (pronoun)’; and ‘so’ is in apposition with ‘all’?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OED gives only *adverb* and *conjunction* in the relevant definition (effectively, *In the way or manner described, indicated, or suggested*).

In OP's context, "the thing told" is that *Harry had never had any money in his life until a month ago*. There's no need to see *so* as a pronoun referencing that "thing told". It's just an adverb, meaning...

> **in a manner embodying/conveying/signifying "the thing told"**
>    ("the thing told" will always have been already mentioned or implied by context).

Thus *so* doesn't refer directly to *"all about having to wear Dudley's old clothes..."* (but it does indirectly, since that clause simply expands on, and is a restatement of, "the thing told").

If there were other constructions where *so* appeared to function as a pronoun, it might be worth seeing it that way here. But I can't think of any such, so I suggest it's best seen  as just another adverbial usage.

---

Note that *to tell* can be used in several ways...

> *[But after a visit from my parents, I told. I was really feeling guilty because [blah blah].](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=nr9wQx_bv2kC&pg=PA145&dq=%22I%20told%20I%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=7SR3UcakDKyh7Ab2wYCAAw&ved=0CEsQ6AEwBTgK#v=onepage&q=%22I%20told%20I%22&f=false)*
>    (intransitive usage, no object)
>
> *[No, that's not the way it was. I told the truth.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=_M6DRFgNPw4C&pg=PA310&dq=%22I%20told%20the%20truth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zyZ3UcirEsfxhQed14G4AQ&ved=0CEUQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=%22I%20told%20the%20truth%22&f=false)*
>    (transitive, direct object = *the thing told*)
>
> *[He asked me what my mission was and I told him.](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=cQd3oXfR1ZwC&pg=PA103&dq=%22I%20told%20him%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=yiV3Ub_5M4W1hAfwwoGICA&sqi=2&ved=0CFcQ6AEwBg#v=onepage&q=%22I%20told%20him%22&f=false)* (there are lots of **told**'s in that link!)
>    (transitive, [in]direct object = *the person told*)
>
> *[I told you the truth I heard from God](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=iL30J5MDRIQC&pg=PA659&dq=%22I%20told%20you%20the%20truth%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Pyh3UfKcEIOHhQf-rIDgCw&ved=0CDkQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=%22I%20told%20you%20the%20truth%22&f=false)*
>    (ditransitive, with the two objects *what was told,* and *to whom*)

---

It's true we can often use *"I told you so"* and *"I told you that"* interchangeably, so possibly even some native speakers already associate *so* with "pronoun" functionality...

> *"He insulted my mother, so I hit him **so**!*"*
>    (where the second *"so"* would be emphatically stressed, and probably accompanied by a gesture)

In that last example, you could perhaps say *so = **this** [gesture]*, making it a "pronoun" usage. But I think it's more straightforward to call it adverbial *so = **like this**, in this way*.

Comment: +1 You might take a look at [this](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/19662/24489). Especially the "authoritative" comment.

Comment: Well, I pretty much agree with the general principle that little is *gained by forcing {so} into one or more of our general part-of-speech categories* cited from CGEL in the answer. But most of JL's comment goes over my head (I'm intrigued as to *"Why you can't do so into the sink"*, though! :). As to the answerer's *We are doctors. **So** are they.*, I think that's also a manifestly adverbial usage *(they **are** [doctors] **in the same way** that we are)*. I see no good reason to classify "so" as a noun usage there.

Comment: Understand: I'm not in any way arguing that it is a pronoun, just that I can understand how someone (several someones, it now appears, including the AHD) might take it to be a pronoun, because it sits in the right place syntactically and exhibits anaphora.

Comment: It is most definitely *not* an adverb in this context; it does not refer to the manner of telling, but to the thing told. The "I told you so"/"I told you that" part of your answer is correct, and that is the way *so* is being used here: "After all, he'd never had any money in his life until a month ago, and he told Ron [that], all about having to wear Dudley's old clothes and never getting proper birthday presents." The punctuation is unfortunate; the comma after "so" should probably be an em dash.

Comment: @Stan: You're presumably one of those *"possibly even some native speakers"* referred to in the sentence before my final example. But consider the discussion under StoneyB's answer (particularly, my [comment about repositioning "so"](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5697/how-to-parse-told-ron-so/5718?noredirect=1#comment8507_5699)). Superficially it might seem "easier" to juxtapose ***so/that*** and thus decide it's a pronoun. But it just doesn't get you anywhere useful, and standard reference sources don't support it. Punctuation is irrelevant to ***real*** (spoken) language, imho.

Comment: Punctuation in written language serves as an admittedly inadequate stand-in for the nuances of "real" language. Things like the lengths of pauses, facial expressions, abrupt changes in tonality and so forth that you would pick up in a face-to-face conversation may be only hinted at in writing, and that leaves two general methods: punctuation in running text; and glossing (which would also include quotative forms interspersed with commentary). I'm afraid that you are just plain wrong here.

Comment: @Stan: I'm not sure what you mean by "plain wrong" there. Serious linguists (the people who actually *study* language, as a *science*) have no significant interest in punctuation. Elements such as phonology/prosody *are* part of "language" by my definition, but facial expressions and gestures aren't (they're just "non-verbal **context**").

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to argue with *so* as a pronoun there, referring to *he'd never had &c* and acting as the object of *tell*; or with *all* as a pronoun in apposition, a restatement of the object; so we have, in effect, a paraphrase of:

> ... he told Ron **that**, **everything** about ...

And yet I'm quite sure that that's dead wrong.

*So* is an adverb with a wide range of meanings, all roughly equivalent to *in that manner*; and *tell ... so* is a fixed phrase meaning *speak ... to that effect*.

And since *all* here can be omitted without materially affecting the syntax, I think it has to be parsed either as an adjective modifying the *about having ...* prepositional phrase, or as a compound preposition, *allabout*—which is certainly how it is pronounced.

So I think what's involved here is a use of *tell* in a double sense: first intransitively, to carry the *told him so* idiom, and then recategorized to carry the *tell him about* idiom. My parse would involve an apposition of two verb phrases, with an ellipsis of the repeated second verb:

> ... he told him so, [told him] all about ...

But I think what we **really** have here is an instance of the language running so fast it tramples grammatical analysis into the mud.

Comment: I thing there might be mis-bracketing:... he told him so, [told him] all about ...

Comment: I don't see any problem with the "standard" approach, whereby *so* is classed as an adverb. Which, incidentally, can often be just as validly placed before as after the verb it modifies. *"I thought Ron was making a mistake, and [I so advised him](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+so+advised+him%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"*. A little stuffy/formal/dated, perhaps, but perfectly grammatical.

Comment: @FumbleFingers  I said it's an adverb. But there's a problem with "I told you so" (or, for that matter, with "I told you"), which is the absence of a DO; so it's easy for a non-native speaker to see *so* as a pronoun, suplying that lack.

Comment: Yeah - But *"Does he know?"* can be answered *"Yes, I told him"*. It doesn't have to be (and normally isn't) *"Yes, I told him **so**"*. It's still not obvious to me why anyone interested in grammatical terminology should shy away from accepting it as an adverbial usage. In OP's context, "the thing told" is that *he'd never had any money in his life until a month ago*. There's no need to envisage *so* as a pronoun referencing "the  thing told". It's just an adverb meaning *in a manner embodying/conveying/signifying "the thing told"* (which will always have been already mentioned/implied).

Comment: @FumbleFingers You know that and I know that; but an ELL who's struggled through the difference between *speak*, *say* and *tell* is looking for that DO; and an ELL who's been around here for a while and sees three or four times a day that any POS can act as any other POS, and who sees a [dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/so) saying something like *so* is "used to refer back to something that has already been mentioned" may very well look at *I told you so* and say "Aha! It quacks like a pronoun! *So* must be a pronoun here!"

Comment: That's a [quack and dirty](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/5686/) approach to POS classification. That poster wants to meaninglessly force any random noun into an adjectival context. This one wants to invent an "undocumented" classification where a little more faith in dictionaries would probably do it. OED gives only *adverb* and *conjunction*, and it obviously ain't the latter. I think I might post an answer out of those comments.